# Amplify amateur errors: Uncaught (in promise) and Each child should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm following Amazon's Getting Started with AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-four/

I've built the app and have it hosted on git. Whenever I refresh the page or re-run "npm start", there are two entries in my notes app, even after I delete them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRlLC.png

When I delete the notes and enter new 'notes' I get the error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." and when I delete the note I get the error: "Uncaught (in promise)" DynamoDB:DynamoDbException

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pMEG.png

Thanks for looking! The code in app.js is below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { API, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { listNotes } from './graphql/queries';
import { createNote as createNoteMutation, deleteNote as deleteNoteMutation } from './graphql/mutations';

const initialFormState = { name: '', description: '' }

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNotes();
  }, []);

  async function onChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.files[0]) return
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setFormData({ ...formData, image: file.name });
    await Storage.put(file.name, file);
    fetchNotes();
  }
  async function fetchNotes() {
  const apiData = await API.graphql({ query: listNotes });
  const notesFromAPI = apiData.data.listNotes.items;
  await Promise.all(notesFromAPI.map(async note => {
    if (note.image) {
      const image = await Storage.get(note.image);
      note.image = image;
    }
    return note;
  }))
  setNotes(apiData.data.listNotes.items);
  }

  async function createNote() {
    if (!formData.name || !formData.description) return;
    await API.graphql({ query: createNoteMutation, variables: { input: formData } });
    if (formData.image) {
      const image = await Storage.get(formData.image);
      formData.image = image;
    }
    setNotes([ ...notes, formData ]);
    setFormData(initialFormState);
  }
  async function deleteNote({ id }) {
    const newNotesArray = notes.filter(note => note.id !== id);
    setNotes(newNotesArray);
    await API.graphql({ query: deleteNoteMutation, variables: { input: { id } }});
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My Notes App</h1>
      <input
        onChange={e => setFormData({ ...formData, 'name': e.target.value})}
        placeholder="Note name"
        value={formData.name}
      />
      <input
        onChange={e => setFormData({ ...formData, 'description': e.target.value})}
        placeholder="Note description"
        value={formData.description}
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <button onClick={createNote}>Create Note</button>
      <div style={{marginBottom: 30}}>
        {
          notes.map(note => (
            <div key={note.id || note.name}>
              <h2>{note.name}</h2>
              <p>{note.description}</p>
              <button onClick={() => deleteNote(note)}>Delete note</button>
              {
                note.image && <img src={note.image} style={{width: 400}} />
              }
            </div>
          ))
        }

      </div>
      <AmplifySignOut />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: Try passing the id from the map function `notes.map((note, id) => (` into the key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the map function to 

`notes.map((note,id) => (<div key={note.id || note.name}>`

I still get an uncaught (in promise) error

0: {path: Array(1), data: null, errorType: "DynamoDB:DynamoDbException", errorInfo: null, locations: Array(1), …}
length: 1

I also tried changing the map function to 
`notes.map((note,id) => (<div key={note.id}>`

but I get an error if the "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
await API.graphql({ query: createNoteMutation, variables: { input: formData } });
```

to

```
const result = await API.graphql({ query: createNoteMutation, variables: { input: formData } });
```

Change the createNote and deleteNote functions to:

````
  async function createNote() {

    if (!formData.name || !formData.description) return;

    const result = await API.graphql({ query: createNoteMutation, variables: { input: formData } });

    if (formData.image) {

      const image = await Storage.get(formData.image);

      formData.image = image;

    }

    setNotes([ ...notes, {...result.data.createNote, ...formData} ]);

    setFormData(initialFormState);

  }

  async function deleteNote( note ) {

    const newNotesArray = notes.filter(n => n.id !== note.id);

    await API.graphql({ query: deleteNoteMutation, variables: { input: { id:note.id } }});

    setNotes(newNotesArray);

  }
    ```
````

Comment: I just fixed it. Should have been
```const result = await API.graphql({ query: createNoteMutation, variables: { input: formData } });```